# proxychains command not found

Tags: proxy, homebrew, telnet

I just installed proxychains-ng on OS X with homebrew (`brew install proxychains-ng`).

When I run `proxychains telnet www.google.com 80`, I get

`proxychains: command not found`.

Similar result when I run `proxychains-ng telnet www.google.com 80`. Any ideas why it's not working?

Answer (score 1):

The right command is `proxychains4`, but you can create a symbolic link:

```
# Ubuntu
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/proxychains4 /usr/local/bin/proxychains

# Darwin
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/proxychains4 /usr/local/bin/proxychains
```

Comment: Take a look here https://github.com/brunowego/cookbooks/blob/develop/proxychains-ng.md to see instructions about how install.